# Help with details in an example showing the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous

Tags: uniform-continuity

Here is a portion of an example in Ross' Elementary Analysis. Definition 19.1 is the definition of uniform continuity.

[image]

What is the rationale for choosing $\frac{\delta}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show (1) we need two numbers $x,y$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Instead of choosing $x$ and $y$ separately, it's easier to decide that $y$ will be $x+$(something small) and focus on choosing $x$. The numbers  $x$ and $x+\delta$ would not work because they do not satisfy the strict inequality $\dots<\delta$. So we use $\delta/2$ instead, because $\delta/2$ is the world's favorite number between $0$ and $\delta$.

Comment: Hmmm... Rather, it seems that the authors use $\delta/2$ because $f(x)\geqslant f(x+\delta/2)+1$ for every $x$ in $(0,1-\delta/2)$. To deal with $g(x)=1/x^{42}$ they might have chosen $y=x+\delta/42$.

Comment: Short of  reading their mind, all I can say that if this proof was written by me, it would have $\delta/2$ regardless of the exponent $p$ in $f(x)=1/x^p$.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform continous functions transform Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences. This function transform the Cauchy sequence $u_n=1/n$  into the unbounded sequence $f(u_n)=n^2$ which is in turn not a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430365/uniform-continuity-and-cauchy-sequences